# Which version of Mongodb should I use?

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor on my ubuntu 10.04 server, and I'm wondering which version of Mongodb I should use?

I do not see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor ships with MongoDB 2.2.  But you should be able to connect to any version of MongoDB that version 1.1.5 of the [JavaScript MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) supports.

The driver's docs don't tell us what versions it supports.  But Mongo's [wire protocol](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol) has been fairly stable, so I'd expect older versions of MongoDB to work well.  Reports appreciated.

Comment: I definitely had problems with an earlier version of MongoDB related to Server side indexing; Sadly I did not write down the version. Thanks for your hard work, Meteor is quite fun.